# How much can the matching number in a graph decrease at most by removing a vertex subset?

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

Let $G$ be a graph and let $v$ be a vertex of $G$. Let $\alpha'(G)$ denote the size of maximaum matchings in $G$.

My question is the following:

**Question 1.** What is the maximum value of $\alpha'(G) - \alpha'(G-v)$, where $G-v$ is the graph obtained from $G$ by removing vertex $v$?

I think $\alpha'(G)-\alpha'(G-v)\le 1$ is correct. Because a vertex can be saturated by at most one edge in a (maximum) matching.

Here is an example I am considering. If we remove vertex $v$, the  matching number decreases by 1. If we remove vertex $u$, the matching number remains unchanged.

[image]

What happens if we extend the situation of removing one vertex to removing a vertex set?

**Question 2.** What is the maximum value of $\alpha'(G) - \alpha'(G-S)$, where $G-S$ is the graph obtained from $G$ by removing vertex set $S$ with $|S|=k$?

Will we obtain an expression in terms of $k$? How about the simple case where $k=2$?

Comment: I see no reason why this difference can be greater than $k$. If $P$ is the maximal matching of graph $G$ and it contains $s\geq k$ edges, then if we remove $k$ vertices even from $P$ we can destroy no more than $k$ edges from $P$.

Comment: @kabenyuk Yes, perhaps it may be more meaningful to consider the cases when  $α'(G)−α'(G−S)$ is equal to $k−m$ where $m$ is a non-negative integer. (Is $k$ tight when $k\ge 2$?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have got some ideas of your question. Let's consider the general situation of the question which is, the maximum value of *α'*(*G*)-*α*'(*G-S*) where *S* is a set of vertex and |*S*|=*k*.

---

Firstly, as you had said before, since a vertex can only be saturated by one edge, it   is obvious that *α*'(*G*) - *α*'(*G-S*)$\leq$*k*
Whether *α*'(*G*) - *α*'(*G-S*) can be tightly equals to k is a more intriguing question.

---

If the graph *G* is a **acyclic graph**, I can prove that the limit of *k* is tight.
**definition:** if a vertex have only one edge connected to other vertexes, we call it a **leaf**

> **Lemma 1** There must be at least one **leaf** to be matched in a maximum matching.

**prove**: We assume that all **leaves** aren't matched, choose one **leaf** randomly and let's call it *u* and the vertex it connected to is *v*.
if *v* is not matched to any other vertex, than let *u* match with *v*, we can obtain another mathcing without disturbing the the previous matching.
if *v* is matched with another vertex, let's say, *w*. Than we can cancel the matching between *w* and *v* and let *u* to be connected with *v* which won't influence the result. So there must be a maximum matching where *u* is matched with *v*.
*Q.E.D.*

> **Lemma 2** We can make the $\alpha$'(G) decrease by one just by deleting one vertex.(that is to say, we can find a way to let *α*'(*G*) - *α*'(*G-v*) = 1)

**prove**: According to **lemma 1**, there must be at least one **leaf** that is in the matching. Let's call it *u* and the vertex it connected to is *v*. If we delete *v*, it is obvious that *u* is useless.(since it isn't connected to any vertex at all!)
If *α*'(*G*) = *α*'(*G-v*), than it means we can have a maximum matching method whose size is as big as the maximum matching after we deleted two adjacent vertexes. 
This as quiet a contradiction because if we let the two vertexes matched, α'(*G*) will definitely raise.
So we proved that *α*'(*G*) $\neq$ *α*'(*G-v*), since we have *α*'(*G*) - *α*'(*G-S*)$\leq$*1*, we can get *α*'(*G*) - *α*'(*G-S*) = *1*
*Q.E.D.*
We find that the graph after we deleted *v* is still a **acyclic graph**, which means we can do the former operation recursively with the help of **Lemma 1** and **Lemma 2** until *α*'(*G-S*) reach zero.

---

So we have solved the situation when *G* is a **acyclic graph**. But when there are **circles** in *G*, I'm not sure whether there is a strict condition for *α*'(*G*) - *α*'(*G-S*) = *k* or not, but I'm sure not all of them can.
Just consider a graph that contains only three vertexes, let's call them *u*, *v* and *w*.
there are three edges between *u* and *v*, *u* and *w*, *v* and *w* respectively, than it can be easy proved that you can't make *α*'(*G*) decrease just by deleting one vertex (the other two can still make a match).

Comment: Your answer is excellent. It reminds me of the idea of "criticality" in graph theory, like the "crossing- critical". I am not sure if there is a definition of a graph that has the matching number greater than or equal to $k$, but removing any vertex results in the matching number  less than $k$. (The crossing number of a graph $G$ is the minimum number of edge crossings over all drawings of $G$ in the plane. A graph $G$ is $k$-crossing-critical if its crossing number is at least $k$, but if we remove any edge of $G$, its crossing number drops below $k$.)

Comment: If your graph has cycles, you can use the complete bipartite graph $K_{n,n}$ to show that the bound $\alpha'(G) - \alpha'(G-S) \leq |S|$ is sharp (think about removing a set of $k$ vertices from just one side).